# Xamarin.Forms Equivelant of UWP's VisualTreeHelper

Tags: xamarin.forms

Does Xamarin.Forms have anything similar to UWP's VisualTreeHelper class? I have a CollectionView for which I want to access the View(s) created by the ItemTemplate. Because I cannot do this using x:Name (because I do not know how many items I will have), I need a way to do it using a collection & indexes. Visual Studio 2019 has a Live Visual Tree tool for Xamarin, so I know what elements I am looking for and where they are located, but I cannot figure out the code to access them. Is there any way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to accomplish?  Directly modifying the views of a templated control is not a good idea.

Comment: I don't really plan on modifying the views, I just need access to them so that I can access their generated data and/or call methods on them. One of the most significant scenarios is my Views that are CollectionViews. I need to synchronize the scroll position of these CollectionViews (once I figure out how to do that), so I obviously need access to them to do this, as well as programmatically select and/or deselect items. I have also had other scenarios of this type, including ones that do not involve CollectionViews & DataTemplates.

Comment: @NathanSokalski Hi, if using **MVVM** to bind data for `CollectionView`, you could get the data from model. Then you will know what the data of each index. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection#single-selection